# Problem with POJO to Schema generation : resolver/expand $ref?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, jackson-databind

I'm trying to generate a JSON schema from a Pojo class using Jackson APIs.
But problem i'm facing is that for some fields, the JSON schema contains `$ref`.
How do I convert from Java POJO to JSON schema without `$ref(references)`.
Or is there a way to further process the JSON schema to resolve the `$ref` ?

Below is my code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);

mapper.setVisibilityChecker(
                mapper.getSerializationConfig().
                getDefaultVisibilityChecker().
                withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY).
                withGetterVisibility(Visibility.NONE));


JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGen = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);

com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema schema = schemaGen.generateSchema(Protocol.class);
```

The part of schema looks like

```
"items" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "$ref" : urn:jsonschema:swift:drivers:nms:traffic:tunnels:core:complexParams:ELSPCosParams"
}
```

But I want inline schema to be generated and not the $ref part.

Can anyone please help or guide how to proceed?